# Сравнение текстовых полей в mysql

Tags: mysql

Как правильнее сравнивать текстовые поля (типа `VARCHAR`), через знак равенства (`=`) или же с помощью `LIKE`?

Например, есть два поля:

```
`fld1` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
`fld2` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
```

Как правильнее написать условие выборки:

```
WHERE `fld1`= `fld2`
```

или же

```
`WHERE `fld1` LIKE `fld2` ?
```

Я склоняюсь к мнению, что второй вариант правильнее, но хотелось бы удостовериться в этом. И ещё вопрос: если второй вариант более правильный, то первый вообще использовать не стоит? Например, если ранее поля `fld1` и `fld2` были типа `INT`, и в хранимых процедурах использовалась конструкция

```
WHERE `fld1`= `fld2`
```

после изменения типа этих полей на `VARCHAR` обязательно менять `=` на `LIKE`, или же это не критично?

**UPD**

И ещё вопрос: как правильно сравнивать поля `VARCHAR` и `INT`?
Почему такой вопрос возник...

Выполнение всех трёх нижеследующих запросов возвращает `1`, т.е. сравнение подтверждает равенство, что вроде бы логично:

```
SELECT '12' = 12;
SELECT '12' LIKE 12;
SELECT '12' = '12';
```

Выполнение следующих двух запросов возвращает `0`, сравнение подтверждает неравенство, что тоже логично:

```
SELECT 'abc' LIKE 0;
SELECT 'abc' = '0';
```

А вот следующих запрос:

```
SELECT 'abc' = 0;
```

возвращает `1`... Почему?..

Comment: если нужно что бы точно совпали то `=` а если нужно сравнить и подстроки то `LIKE` То есть что бы первая строка была вложена во вторую то сравнить надо с `LIKE`. Подробно про `LIKE` тут http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_comparison_functions.html

Comment: а чего вы хотите достичь ? `abc` = '%' даст false потому что строки ну совершенно не равны, даже намека на совпадение нет. Однако `abc` like `%` даст true, потому что под _маску_ `%` попадают вообще любые строки. так что если вам нужно знать о точном равенстве то like нельзя использовать ни в коем случае

Comment: @Mike, обновила вопрос.

Comment: like проверяет именно по маске. а следовательно он ожидет вторым параметром получить маску. т.е. _строку_ а так как там _число_ то он приводит тип и получает `'abc' like '0'`. А оператору `=` все равно что сравнивать. И MySQL предпочитает сверять числа и приводит строку abc к числу, а такое приведение типов дает 0, т.е. `0=0`. Но в любых непонятных ситуациях следует самостоятельно приводить данные к одному типу перед работой с ними, например с помощью cast, что бы работало именно так как задумано

Comment: @Mike, благодарю, в общем-то, это мне и хотелось узнать. Если опубликуете, приму как ответ :)

Comment: *Как правильнее написать условие выборки* Существуют условия, в которых каждый из вариантов станет ошибочным. И даже возможны условия, когда оба варианта ошибочны - правда, на показанных описаниях полей только искусственно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это совершенно разные операторы, служащие для решения абсолютно разных задач. `=` сравнивает свои операнды, числа с числами или строки со строками, проверяет точное равенство аргументов. `like` это поиск в строке по маске, сравнивать им строки на точное равенство нельзя.

Оператор `like` в качестве второго аргумента ожидает получить маску, а маска это *строка*, поэтому перед операцией все типы данных MySQL пытается привести к строковому типу, в результате `0` будет приведен к `'0'`, а `'abc'` останется неизменной, так как она уже строка. В итоге будет произведено сравнение по маске `'abc' like '0'`, которое даст ложь.

В случае же оператора `=`, если типы операндов отличаются, MySQL приведет их к одному перед операцией сравнения, в случае строки и числа скорее всего к числу. А по хорошему вы должны давать этому оператору однотипные операнды изначально, что бы точно понимать как пойдет сравнение, приведя их заранее к нужному.

```
select 'abc' = 0;   типы приводятся к числу 'abc'=>0 = 0, результат - истина
select 'abc' = '0'; приводить типы не надо, сравниваются строки, результат - ложь
select 'abc'=cast(0 as char);     Тут явное приведение типов к строке - ложь.
select cast('abc' as unsigned)=0; Сравнение чисел, как в первом примере - истина
```